# CMAKE ignores all settings about specifying the compiler

Tags: c++, cmake

On Windows 10 with VS2017 and LLVM installed

and CMAKE just takes VC compiler as default and ignores both `set` command in the CMakeLists.txt and command line `-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER`

I have no idea how to make it use LLVM Clang

I checked out many existing questions but they do not work for me

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "C:\\Program Files\\LLVM\\bin\\Clang++")
project(CMakeTest1 VERSION 0.0.0 LANGUAGES CXX)
aux_source_directory(. MAINDIR)
add_executable(CMakeTest1 ${MAINDIR})
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

running command with git bash

```
***@DESKTOP-8KJ4J0H MINGW64 /d/CMakeTest1
$ cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\Clang++" .
-- Building for: Visual Studio 15 2017
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.13.26129.0
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.13.26128/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.13.26128/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: D:/CMakeTest1
```

my CXX compiler identification is forced to be MSVC and cannot be changed by any method.

no idea why

EDITED:
what i wanna strongly declare is, i swear and clearly know that i CLEANED ALL GENERATED FILES form the folder and there are ONLY JUST CMakeLists.txt and main.cpp existing. and I DON'T WANT TO BE ASSUMED having old cache files unremoved

Comment: What is the content of `CMakeCache.txt`? Have you try to remove this file before run cmake?

Comment: As explained in [the documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_COMPILER.html#variable:CMAKE_%3CLANG%3E_COMPILER), once set it can't be changed. You must remove *all* CMake generated project files and remake it from fresh with `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` set to the compiler you want to use.

Comment: On a slightly related note, it's not recommended to create the CMake build/project files in the same directory as the rest of your source tree. Create a sub-directory (e.g. `mkdir build`), go to that directory (`cd build`) and generate the build files there (`cmake ..`). This will make it *much* easier to regenerate your project from scratch, as needed when changing compiler, since you just remove the separate build directory.

Comment: what i wanna strongly declare is, i swear and clearly know that i cleaned all generated files form the folder and there are only just CMakeLists.txt and main.cpp existing @hgminh

Comment: Works well for me using Cmake v3.10 on linux, Clang is used. Can you use CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS to ensure clang is not used ?

Comment: I tried using cmake in a build folder and that causes `cmake --build ..` fail with `Error: could not load cache`

Comment: `CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

    CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS


-- Build files have been written to: D:/CMakeTest1` @Charles Gueunet

Comment: @Alsein You need to use -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON to use it, as -D is used to set a variable on command line.
PS: Why do you use --build with cmake ?

Comment: yes im sure i used -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON @Charles Gueunet

Comment: btw is there any disadvantage using  --build?@Charles Gueunet

Comment: You can't declare/change the compiler for Visual Studio Solutions generator via `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER`. Changing the compiler in VS works by defining the toolset you want to use. Use `cmake -T"LLVM-vs2014"`.

Comment: @Alsein Export compile command is only supported by Makefile/Ninja generator and as told by hgminh it seems you are not using these. That is why you don't have this command enable.
For --build, I seen no disadvantages, I was just curious.

Comment: i dont wanna use anything from VS so that it would work not only on windows @Florian

Comment: so is there any way to make it work with LLVM Clang?@Charles Gueunet

Comment: @Alsein if you use cmake-gui, it is easier to change the generator used. Can you try it ?

Answer (score 1):

This may be due to default [generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-generators.7.html) of `CMake` in Windows.

```
-- Building for: Visual Studio 15 2017
...
```

You can change the generator by adding `-G <generator name>` to the command line. In your case, I think `-G 'MSYS Makefiles'` may work.

Comment: `CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "MinGW Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.`

Comment: sorry, I copy the wrong one, try `-G 'MSYS Makefiles'` instead. I think it should work on git bash

Comment: `CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "MSYS Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.`

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` was inferred from your generator (The latest *Visual Studio* is used by default on windows), so it is `cl.exe`.

In order to switch to `clang` you should use other generator e.g. `Ninja` or `Unix Makefiles`.

If you want to use VS with `clang-cl.exe`, you need to set platform toolset to appropriate version by adding flag `-TLLVM-vs2014`.

See [this instructions](https://github.com/boostorg/hana/wiki/Setting-up-Clang-on-Windows) for more info.