Unable to have clang-cl use wasm-ld as the linker
I never seem to be able to get clang-cl to link with wasm-ld instead of the default lld linker.
CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18.0)

project(wasm_test)

set(CMAKE_LINKER "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/Llvm/x64/bin/wasm-ld.exe")
set(CMAKE_C_LINK_EXECUTABLE "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/Llvm/x64/bin/wasm-ld.exe")
set(CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/Llvm/x64/bin/wasm-ld.exe")

add_compile_options("-fuse-ld=C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/Llvm/x64/bin/wasm-ld.exe")
add_compile_options("--target=wasm32-unknown-wasi -nostdlib -Wl,--no-entry")

add_executable(wasm_test add.cpp)

CMakePresets.json
{
    "version": 8,
    "configurePresets": [
        {
            "name": "clang-cl",
            "displayName": "Clang 17.0.3 (MSVC CLI) for MSVC 17.10.35027.167 (Visual Studio Community 2022 Release - amd64)",
            "description": "Using compilers: C = C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\Llvm\\x64\\bin\\clang-cl.exe, CXX = C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\Llvm\\x64\\bin\\clang-cl.exe",
            "generator": "Visual Studio 17 2022",
            "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/out/build/${presetName}",
            "toolset": "ClangCL,host=x64",
            "cacheVariables": {
                "CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX": "${sourceDir}/out/install/${presetName}",
                "CMAKE_C_COMPILER": "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/Llvm/x64/bin/clang-cl.exe",
                "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER": "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/Llvm/x64/bin/clang-cl.exe"
            }
        }
    ],
    "buildPresets": [
        {
            "name": "clang-Release",
            "displayName": "Clang 17.0.3 (MSVC CLI) for MSVC 17.10.35027.167 (Visual Studio Community 2022 Release - amd64) - Release",
            "configurePreset": "clang-cl",
            "configuration": "Release"
        }
    ]
}

Configure output
[main] Configuring project: wasm 
[driver] NOTE: You are configuring with preset Clang 17.0.3 (MSVC CLI) for MSVC 17.10.35027.167 (Visual Studio Community 2022 Release - amd64), but there are some overrides being applied from your VS Code settings.
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:/dev/project/wasm/out/install/clang-cl "-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/Llvm/x64/bin/clang-cl.exe" "-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/Llvm/x64/bin/clang-cl.exe" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang-cl -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang-cl -SC:/dev/project/wasm -BC:/dev/project/wasm/out/build/clang-cl -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -T ClangCL,host=x64
[cmake] -- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.22621.0 to target Windows 10.0.19045.
[cmake] -- The C compiler identification is Clang 17.0.3 with MSVC-like command-line
[cmake] -- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 17.0.3 with MSVC-like command-line
[cmake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
[cmake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
[cmake] -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/Llvm/x64/bin/clang-cl.exe - skipped
[cmake] -- Detecting C compile features
[cmake] -- Detecting C compile features - done
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
[cmake] -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/Llvm/x64/bin/clang-cl.exe - skipped
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compile features
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
[cmake] -- Configuring done (3.7s)
[cmake] -- Generating done (0.0s)
[cmake] -- Build files have been written to: C:/dev/project/wasm/out/build/clang-cl

Build output
[main] Building folder: C:/dev/project/wasm/out/build/clang-cl 
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --build C:/dev/project/wasm/out/build/clang-cl --config Release --target wasm_test --
[build] MSBuild version 17.10.4+10fbfbf2e for .NET Framework
[build] 
[build]   1>Checking Build System
[build]   Building Custom Rule C:/dev/project/wasm/CMakeLists.txt
[build] clang-cl : warning : argument unused during compilation: '/O2' [-Wunused-command-line-argument] [C:\dev\project\wasm\out\build\clang-cl\wasm_test.vcxproj]
[build] clang-cl : warning : argument unused during compilation: '/Ob2' [-Wunused-command-line-argument] [C:\dev\project\wasm\out\build\clang-cl\wasm_test.vcxproj]
[build] clang-cl : warning : argument unused during compilation: '-fuse-ld=C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/Llvm/x64/bin/wasm-ld.exe' [-Wunused-command-line-argument] [C:\dev\project\wasm\out\build\clang-cl\wasm_test.vcxproj]
[build] lld-link : error : wasm_test.dir\Release\add.obj: unknown file type [C:\dev\project\wasm\out\build\clang-cl\wasm_test.vcxproj]
[proc] The command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --build C:/dev/project/wasm/out/build/clang-cl --config Release --target wasm_test -- exited with code: 1
[driver] Build completed: 00:00:00.643
[build] Build finished with exit code 1

I have tried everything that I can think of yet I don't seem to get any closer to any solution. My hoped would be that -fuse-ld=wasm-ld would work but it has not.
Any help would be much appreciated!

You are specifying linking options with command add_compile_options, which is intended for compile options only. Instead use add_link_options command.

Note also, that Visual Studio generator ignores compiler and linker settings: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49531758/cmake-ignores-all-settings-about-specifying-the-compiler. That is, your variables CMAKE_C_COMPILER and CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER are ignored. The variables CMAKE_C_LINK_EXECUTABLE and CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE are set incorrectly: they should contain not the linker, but a rule (command line): https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_LINK_EXECUTABLE.html. Lucky, these variable are ignored too.

Okay so there is no way with Visual Studio as a generator to use the wasm-ld linker instead of the default one?

Rule variables, such as CMAKE_C_LINK_EXECUTABLE, should essentially never be set in project code. They're an internal implementation detail of CMake and you use them at your own peril.

Also, add_(compile|link)_options takes a ;-separated CMake list, not a space-separated list.

It's the same problem when using NMake as a generator. The compiler (clang-cl or clang, tried both) always defaults to using lld-link as linker instead of wasm-ld no matter the flags I try.
